# What is the rationale for the default uncaught signal handler policy in Java?

Tags: java, exception

A great deal has been written about the wisdom of exceptions in general and the use of checked vs. unchecked exceptions in Java in particular, but I'm interested in seeing a defense of the decision to make thread termination the default policy instead of application termination the way it is in C++.  This choice seems extremely dangerous to me: some condition that the programmer didn't plan for randomly causes some part of the program to die after logging a stack trace but the rest of the program soldiers resolutely on, what could go wrong?  My intuition and experience say that a lot of things can go wrong here and that the default policy is the sort of thing that should only be selected specifically by someone who has a specific reason for choosing it, so what's the upside to this strategy which has such a seemingly large downside?  Am I overestimating the risk?

EDIT: based on the answers so far, I feel that I need to be more focused in my description of the dangers that I perceive; I'm talking about the case of an application which uses multiple thread (e.g. in a thread pool), to update shared state.  I recognize that this policy does not present a problem for single-threaded applications.

EDIT2: You can see that there is an awareness of these risks among the language maintainers from the explanation for why the Thread.stop() method was deprecated (found here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/concurrency/threadPrimitiveDeprecation.html).  The exact same issues apply when a thread dies unexpectedly due to uncaught exceptions.  They must have designed the JVM so that all monitors are automatically unlocked when a thread dies, which seems like a poor implementation choice; having a thread die while it has a monitor locked should be an indication that the entire program should die because the alternative is almost certain to be internal inconsistency in some shared state.

Comment: In Java, each exception has to be handled somewhere. The default exception handler causes termination of JVM. How is that different than the application termination in C++?

Comment: @Usman - my understanding is that you are not correct here; the default uncaught exception handler terminates only the individual thread in which the exception occurs, not the JVM.  Other threads proceed normally.

Comment: Fair enough (and it allowed me to revise my understandings :)). Let me rephrase. In Java unhandled exceptions travels upward in the stack of the thread where it was thrown. I believe Java specifications does not define how to behave if there is no default unhandled exception handler defined. Sun JVM (for instance) just print the stacktrace as its default behavior for unhandled exceptions. You can define your own exception handler though: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/index.html?java/lang/Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler.html

Comment: It's difficult to tell exactly what the standard is, but I found the following in the doc for class Thread: "... The Java Virtual Machine continues to execute threads until either of the following occurs:

    * The exit method of class Runtime has been called and the security manager has permitted the exit operation to take place.
    * All threads that are not daemon threads have died, either by returning from the call to the run method or by throwing an exception that propagates beyond the run method."

Answer (score 1):

@BD, Not sure what your what your experience says about this because you haven't explained it here. But, here is what I have experienced as a developer:

1. Generally, it is a bad idea to make application fail if one of its component has failed (temporarily or permanently) due to any reason like DB restart or some file being replaced. for example if I introduced a new type of trade in system and some issue comes in, it shouldn't shutdown my application.
2. Applications like web/application servers should be able to continue to work and responding to users even if any of its deployment is throwing any weird exception/s.

As per your worry on exceptions, generally all applications have a health monitoring system which monitors their health like CPU/Disk/RAM usage or errors in logs etc. and fire alerts accordingly.

I hope this should resolve your confusion.

Comment: My experience is with applications containing many cooperating threads with long lifetimes. In this situation, an uncaught exception indicates that some important part of the program is now broken in a completely unexpected way, potentially resulting in severe corruption of data structures and incorrect behavior. Web applications tend to be very transactional, and the loss of a single transaction is generally not critical; only the "average" behavior is important, but many applications do not share this property and are thus inherently unsafe with a policy that allows threads to die randomly.

Answer (score 1):

From discussing this issue with a co-worker and also reviewing the answers received so far, I have formed a supposition here, and would like to get some feedback.

I suspect that the decision to make this behavior the default has its roots in the philosophy that defined the early development of language, as well as its early environment.

As part of the original philosophy, programmers/designers were expected to use checked exceptions, and the language enforces that checked exceptions which may be emitted by a method call (i.e. have been declared in the method definition) must be handled in the calling method, or else be declared by it to "officially" pass the responsibility to higher-level callers.  Common practice has moved sharply away from the use of checked exceptions, not to mention the fact that one of the most commonly occurring exceptions in practice, NullPointerException, is unchecked.  As a result of this, programmers must now assume that any method call can generate an unchecked exception, and the corollary to this is that any code which updates shared data in a concurrent context must implement transactional semantics for these updates in order to be fully correct.  My experience is that most developers don't really understand this even if they do understand the basics of multi-threaded development, such as avoiding deadlock when managing critical sections with synchronization.  The default uncaught exception handler behavior exacerbates the problem by masking its effects: in C++, it wouldn't matter if an uncaught exception would result in corrupted shared state because the program is dead anyway, but in Java the program will continue to limp along as best it can despite the fact that it is very likely to no longer be operating correctly.

The environmental factor is that single-threaded programs were likely the norm when the language was first developed, so the default behavior masqueraded as the correct one.  The rise of multi-core architectures and increased usage of thread pools exposes the threat more broadly, and commonly applied approaches such as use of immutable objects can only go so far to solve it (hint for some: ConcurrentMap is probably not as safe as you think it is).  My experience so far is that people who deny this risk are not being paranoid enough relative to the actual safety requirements of their code, but I would love to be proved wrong.

I suspect that modifying uncaught exception handlers to terminate the program should be the standard procedure required by most development organizations; at the very least this should be done for thread pools which are known to update shared state based on incoming inputs.

Comment: I would posit that the fundamental weakness lies in the facts that (1) the semantics of "catch" imply that it is expected to resolve the exception; there should be an idiomatic way of specifying code which will be triggered by unexpected exceptions but is *not* expected to resolve them; (2) if `bar` calls `foo` which is declared as `throws WoozleException`, but `bar` doesn't expect any situations to arise where `foo` would actually throw `WoozleException`, there should be a way for `bar` to declare this so that if `foo` does throw `WoozleException`, it will get wrapped in `RuntimeException`.

Comment: As things sit, there's no nice mechanism via which `bar` can distinguish between a `WoozleException` that it has thrown, or versus one which was *unexpectedly* thrown from a method `bar` called, even though such exceptions should almost certainly be handled differently.  Further, the proper way to minimize the danger from unexpected exceptions is not to have them kill the whole application, but rather have the stack unwinding explicitly invalidate data structures that may have been damaged.  If some code acquires a locked resource and then exits via unexpected exception...

Comment: ...the code should neither keep the lock nor release it; instead, it should invalidate the lock so that present or future attempts to acquire it will immediately throw an exception.  When such an approach is followed, exceptions which really should bring down the system are apt to do so in short order, but exceptions whose damage is contained to a small subsystem will only affect that subsystem.

Comment: @supercat - Your (abridged) quote "Further, the proper way to minimize the danger from unexpected exceptions is ... have the stack unwinding explicitly invalidate data structures that may have been damaged" is describing the requirement for transactional semantics, which would need to be implemented as part of monitor synchronization to be supported by the language; this still leaves any code based on a subclass of Lock or Latch in danger of failure.  The general problem of invalidating damaged data structures sounds undecidable to me but my theoretical formalism skills are a bit weak.

Answer (score 0):

Normal (no GUI, no container)  applications exit on uncaught exceptions - the default behavior is fine - as same as you wanted.

A GUI based application, it will be nice to to show error message and able to handle the error more usefully - for example we could submit a defect report with some additional information.

The behavior is fully changeable by providing  thread specific exception handler- that could include application exit.

[Here](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=229) are some useful notes

Comment: Depends the definition of "normal" that you choose.  In my experience, a "normal" application has no GUI and no container but uses thread pools to take advantage of multi-core architectures.  As multi-core becomes more important to performance, this default behavior becomes more dangerous.  Even a GUI application can be at risk if it uses thread pools to process incoming data and update shared state.